# Using Variable in the query

Tags: sqlite, variables

I'm struggling to make these two lines work without error.

```
campaignName = result['campaign_name']
db_conn.execute('INSERT INTO Report (CAMPAIGN) VALUES ("' + campaignName + '")')
```

I thought that the "'" in "result['campaign_name']" was the problem but even if I assigned the variable the error is persistent.

The error:

[image]

Thank you,

EDIT: I've modified my request to:

```
db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO Report (CAMPAIGN) VALUES ('" + str(campaignName.encode()) + "')")
```

And the script stops at the first dash "-".
[image]

Comment: ever heard of SQL injection? no? you should check it out - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciNHn38EyRc

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the exact SQL command that ends up being executed.  Also, doing it this way leaves you wide open for an SQL injection attack.

Comment: `db_conn.execute('INSERT INTO Report (CAMPAIGN) VALUES (%s)', [campaignName])` is a lot safer.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you but I got an error "near "%": syntax error".
"

Comment: @JohnGordon INSERT INTO Report (CAMPAIGN) VALUES ("X574485JGF-P-TB")

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for strings.  That same command should work with single quotes.

Comment: db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO Report (CAMPAIGN) VALUES ('" + campaignName + "')") Still not working. Unless I don't get what you mean :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

```
db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO Report (CAMPAIGN) VALUES (?)", (campaignName,))
```